# Migrating WordPress free website with own developed python or JavaScript website

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, wordpress

I want to start an educational website with text material, assignments and video tutorials. And I future I want to extend the same for selling my graphic designs. So to start this I was thinking to start with free WordPress website and slowly migrate this website with my own developed Django (Python) and JavaScript website. I am learning python and JavaScript and doesn't start development yet.
**So my question is is its fine and in right direction to start free WordPress website for now and then migrate with same domain to my own developed?**

Comment: This is a metter of opnion, so If you don't know JS and Python yet I think that can be a good idea start with Wordpress cms while you study,  but be in mind that this will cust you some time too,  as for the "migration",  there is no problem to change of server or tecnology etc, just keep the same domain and you should be fine

Comment: Very much thanking you for the kind guidance. So as according to your guidance I have one more question. Is there is any way by which i can host Django website free for at least one year? And which is flexible to update the website for new features and functionalities?

Comment: I don't think so, but if you aren't so attached to Djando you can try the free server "000webhost" but be aware that is only for practice not production, so if you really want develop a website you'll have to spend some money for sure

Comment: Ok, very much thanking you for the kind guidance. I will try both wordpress and 000webhost (and parallely work on developing my own website) and select which option is good for me for temporary work.